# Why is a UITableViewCell detailTextLabel optional in Swift whereas the textLabel is not

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I think I somehow got the different between "?" and "!" in swift language.
But while working I faced something that made me more confused.

While working with tableview I found the following datatypes in `UITableViewCell`

`textLabel`   and    `detailTextLabel?`

My question is: why is `detailTextLabel?` optional even if textLabel may be nil too??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `detailTextLabel` is optional because it can potentially be nil. Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/detailTextLabel):

> If the style doesn’t support detail labels, nil is returned. See
> UITableViewCellStyle for descriptions of the main label in currently
> defined cell styles.

So if your table view style doesn't support detail labels accessing the detailTextLabel will return nil. Hence its optional.

The textLabel on the other hand is created if needed hence it is not an optional:)

Comment: But textLabel may be nil also!!

Comment: @Elsammak No, textLabel will always be created when accessing it. detailTextLabel can be nil depending on your cell style

Comment: @Elsammak great to hear it! Don't forget to accept my answer:) enjoy your day