# Why is a UITableViewCell textLabel property optional?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

A `UITableViewCell`'s `detailTextLabel` [should be optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912186/why-is-a-uitableviewcell-detailtextlabel-optional-in-swift-whereas-the-textlabel), which is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/detailTextLabel), but why is the `textLabel` property optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: To save resources. The textLabel property is optional to allow for the UILabel to be lazily initialized. In other words, the property stays nil unless you actually attempt to access it.

You can verify this in the debugger by examining an instance of your UITableViewCell:

```
let cell = dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(MyCell.cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell

// check cell.textLabel here in the debugger. should be nil.

cell.textLabel.text = "test"   // creates textLabel via lazy initialization
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is not documented properly, it follows the same rules - right style has to be set. That is, if you are using custom cells - usually configured through interface builder, custom cell is initialized - and in that case none of the default views is added to the cell, because it would be wasteful.

If you use any other style than custom cell, it will always have first label initialized, so you can use it without worrying (but definition obviously cannot change in that case, so it will be always declared as optional).